# Slack theme backticked-text format extremely annoying - can I change it?

Tags: slack

I use some Slack space of this company I work for. I'm not sure whether it's a slack default, or the theme that space uses, but when I entered backticked text (i.e. `like this`), I get:

[image]

i.e. the text is bright red over light gray. Contrast is low!

Can I change/override this somehow without being an administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. While you have a lot of options for changing how Slack looks, you can not change the style for how code formatted text is shown.

Comment: I accept, but unfortunately this is not a helpful answer :-(

Comment: I wish I had  a better answer for you. But if you really need this I would recommend to tell the Slack team. They might include it in a future release.

Comment: I actually have. They gave me the standard boilerplate response and that was that. No recognition of the problem.